# Mysql, Sumar con una condicion

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando sumar un tiempo segun una condicion pero no encuentro la manera agradeceria su colaboracion.

Al momento tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT 
    u.src,
    u.accountcode,
    COUNT(*) AS cantidad,
    SUM(u.disposition = 'ANSWERED') AS contestadas,
    SUM(u.disposition = 'NO ANSWER') AS No_contestadas,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ROUND(u.duration))) AS tiempomuerto,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ROUND(u.billsec))) AS totaltiempo
FROM
    asteriskdb.cdr u
WHERE
    u.start != ''
        AND CHARACTER_LENGTH(src) = 4
        AND start BETWEEN CAST('2018-09-13' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-14' AS DATE)
        AND lastapp = 'dial'
        AND dcontext != 'predictivo'
GROUP BY u.src
ORDER BY totaltiempo DESC;
```

Lo que necesito es sumar el valor del campo billsec como tiempo muerto,Pero condicionar que sume solo cuando el campo disposition sea No answer.

Resultado

```
'4313', 'BAL', '105', '82', '23', NULL, '02:10:21'
'4818', 'CID', '164', '93', '71', '03:14:00', '02:09:37'
'4323', 'BL', '102', '72', '30', NULL, '01:51:27'
'4054', 'CO', '122', '74', '48', '02:38:18','01:51:00'
'4052', 'O', '265', '65', '199', '03:14:55', '01:49:48'
'4065', 'd', '150', '105', '45', NULL, '01:46:58'
'4315', 'BANL','85', '68', '17', NULL, '01:40:05'
'4108', 'RE', '15', '6', '9', '01:44:47', '01:37:58'
'4509', 'C', '112', '95', '17', NULL,'01:36:29'
'4513', 'C', '108', '62', '46', '02:09:59', '01:36:06'
'4816', 'C', '137', '63', '74', '02:25:00', '01:31:06'
'4317', 'BL', '76', '58', '18', NULL, '01:25:09'
```

Comment: billsec lo estás sumando en totaltiempo y duration es el que sumas en tiempomuerto, cuál debe ser?

Comment: Hola, Gracias por responder. LO SIENTO !!!! Describi mal el campo. !!!
Necesito sumar el campo duration, mientras el campo disposition sea "NO_ANSWER"

Comment: Prueba a ver si te funciona así: `(CASE WHEN u.disposition = 'NO ANSWER' THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ROUND(u.duration))) END) AS tiempomuerto`

Comment: De antemano agradezo mucho tu ayuda
Teoricamente esta funcionando, pero veo algo super confuso,  no deberia retornar 0 . por que el campo duration No es nullo y siempre tiene datos sin importar que disposition sea  "ANSWERED" O "NO ANSWER".

Comment: Pruebalo sin el `ELSE` amigo, te recomiendo que si vas a colocar código edites la pregunta y lo añadas. Aquí solo coloca lo que te sucede.

Comment: Ups! Lo siento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba agregandole `CASE` a tu campo de esta manera:

```
SELECT 
    u.src,
    u.accountcode,
    COUNT(*) AS cantidad,
    SUM(u.disposition = 'ANSWERED') AS contestadas,
    SUM(u.disposition = 'NO ANSWER') AS No_contestadas,
    (CASE WHEN u.disposition = 'NO ANSWER' 
        THEN SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ROUND(u.duration))) END) AS tiempomuerto,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(ROUND(u.billsec))) AS totaltiempo
FROM
    asteriskdb.cdr u
WHERE
    u.start != ''
        AND CHARACTER_LENGTH(src) = 4
        AND start BETWEEN CAST('2018-09-13' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-14' AS DATE)
        AND lastapp = 'dial'
        AND dcontext != 'predictivo'
GROUP BY u.src
ORDER BY totaltiempo DESC;
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Agregue el resultado en la pregunta, El tema es que realmente no puede SER NULL! Por que el campo duration siempre tiene datos > 0 .

Comment: El `NULL` te lo devuelve cuando no acumulas nada en el campo.

Comment: Funciona, aunque estoy en busca del ¿Porque retorna Null?. Pues no encuentro error, reviso registro por registro y deberia sumar  Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te funciono valida la respuesta como buena para que otro usuario pueda usarla.

Comment: El `NULL` lo devuelve cuando no cumple con la condición del `CASE` o no acumulaste nada.